# (node:8232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error could not find chaincode with name

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have (successfully) deployed my network with:

```
composer network deploy -a health-network.bna -p hlfv1 -i PeerAdmin -s randomString
```

However following line in my node JS file executed from command prompt errors out:

```
return businessNetworkConnection.connect('hlfv1', nameSpace, 'PeerAdmin', 'randomString');
```

Error message:

> (node:8232) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection......Error trying to query chaincode.
>   Error could not find chaincode with name net.digitalHealth.Network ....

Wondering why it's not connecting when the network is successfully deployed ? Appreciate any clues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've used the namespace `net.digitalHealth.Network` as the name of the business network. From the output of the deploy command that you posted in Rocket.Chat, this is wrong; you should use the name of the business network `digital-health-network`.

Comment: Indeed!  Thanks Simon for help... I was mixing up business network with the namespace variable in my model file ... :-(